# object slicing issue?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm having a strange problem when I inspect the elements of a vector that should polymorphically point to derived objects through base class pointers.

this is my vector:

```
std::vector<Gun*> weapons;
```

this is the instantiation:

```
weapons.reserve(3);
weapons.push_back(new Pistol());
weapons.push_back(new Rifle());
weapons.push_back(new Shotgun());
```

This works fine, but as soon as the constructor exits the objects are now of the base class type, not the derived type. Why is this happening?

Comment: how about showing the "access violation warning"

Comment: Perhaps the objects in your vector are being deleted.  Showing us the code in `Brain` that manages the vector would be useful.  Also, you are indeed using raw pointers in your vector... not `auto_ptr` right?

Comment: Something odd has happened here. The question doesn't seem to match its answers at all. It looks to me like the OP defaced his own question with an edit, but I'm not confident enough to revert.

Answer (score 1):

You have some bugs:

```
std::vector<Bullet> Bullets();
```

Returns a copy of bullets, not the underlying object. So when you do:

```
Bullets().push_back(Bullet(Position(), Rotation(), velocity, Colour()));
```

It does not do what you expect it to do.

You most likely want both:

```
const std::vector<Bullet>& Bullets() const;
std::vector<Bullet>& Bullets();
```

That being said, like @John said, the Access violation is most likely a problem with the weapons array not being large enough (perhaps because of the same bug above). The bug would be in the code that populates weapons. You say RIFLE is 2, but from the code you posted it is actually at index 1, not 2, so I'm guessing you have SHOTGUN set to 3 when it should be 2, which is out of the bounds of the array, hence the access protection error. Classic off-by-one.

Comment: out of interest, why would I need both? Oh and also RIFLE is at index 1, it was a typo in my question.

Comment: I made those changes and the problem still occurs at the same line.

Comment: You'd want the const version if you ever past the Gun by const ref, you may still want to access the contents in const context. The bug is still somewhere else you haven't posted here; the code as posted does not slice. I'd try to boil it down to a minimal reproducer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be slicing the objects in any way -- that's probably not the problem.

The most likely suspect is the way you are accessing the `vector` and the probability that there aren't as many items in the `vector` as you think there should be:

`weapons[RIFLE]`

How do you know that there is a valid object here?  Given that you're getting an access violation, it seems likely that there is no valid object at that index.

You should be doing something more along the lines of:

```
if( weapons.size() >= RIFLE )
{
  Gun* gun = weapons.at(RIFLE);
  gun->Ammo();
}
else
{ 
  cerr << "WHOA!  Something blowed up...";
}
```

Comment: but if I break the code and examine the vector, there are indeed objects at that index. 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Trust me -- do what I've suggested, and chances are very good that you will see what the problem is.

Comment: It dumps a string to the stadard output, typically.

Comment: also it doesn't recognise cerr

Comment: @JohnDibling `cerr` outputs to standard error, never to standard out.  Both of these may be connected to the same device, but I wouldn't say that's necessarily typical (except when both are connected to `/dev/null`, because I'm running a demon).  It's "typical" to redirect output at times, and most of the time, only standard out will be redirected; standard error will still end up on the screen (which is the point of using it---redirecting standard out won't cause your error messages to disappear).

Comment: @James:  Thanks for that.  I was super-lazy in answering that question.

Comment: Can you reduce e the problem further? If you could provide a minimal and complete program I can compile and run which duplicates the issue, ill be able to debug further. As a side benefit, you'll very possibly find the pro lemon yourself during this exercise.